# How many digits has $\sqrt{2}$?

Tags: real-numbers

How many digits has $\sqrt{2}$? Countable or uncountable many?

Comment: Can you elaborate? what do you mean by how many decimals?

Comment: Countably infinite many.

Comment: Well, so $\sqrt 2 = 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {a_n}{10^n}$ for $a_n\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.   The $\{a_n\}$ are countable, clearly.  Is this what you meant?

Comment: Every real number has countably many digits in its decimal expansion. Did you really mean to ask whether or not it is repeating? Note that a real number has an eventually repeating decimal expansion if and only if it is rational. This characterizes rational numbers.

Comment: I am curious how you would write down an uncountable number of digits?

Comment: @copper.hat: Simply define a function $f:[0,1]\to\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$?

Comment: @copper.hat And how would you write down a countable number of digits?

Comment: @Aqua: Write down one digit every minute :-).

Comment: @copper.hat OK, then please do write down it decimal expansion.

Comment: Still not sure the question is clear.  With the standard definition of "digit", it's clear that the answer is "countable".  Or were you asking about a non-standard use of the term?

Comment: @Aqua: It is straightforward to write down an algorithm to print the digits of any number $x$ whose appropriately weighted sum converges to $x$. Are you asking if all digits are zero after a certain point? Presumably you are aware that any real has a decimal (or binary, or whatever) expansion.

Answer (score 5):

$\sqrt{2}$ can be viewed as the limit of the sequence $1, 1.4, 1.41,...$ so countably many.

Note that any real number has thus at most countably many digits since it is the limit of the sequence that consists of its digits i.e. if $a\in \mathbb{R}$ then $a = \lim_{n\to +\infty}{\frac{\lfloor{10^{n}a}\rfloor}{10^{n}}}$.

Comment: Which sequence is this exactly? What is it next term and what is it 1000 term?

Comment: @Aqua this is the sequence whose nth term is the decimal expansion of $\sqrt{2}$ truncated to n digits. $u_n = \frac{\lfloor{10^{n}*\sqrt{2}}\rfloor}{10^{n}}$

Answer (score 2):

There is a first digit, a second digit, a third, etc., and there are no other digits. So, countably infinite.

More formally: we can put the digits in $\sqrt{2}$ and their position within it in a bijection with the natural numbers. So, countably infinite.

\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 4 & 1 & 4 & 2 &...\\
\updownarrow & \updownarrow & \updownarrow & \updownarrow & \updownarrow &...\\
1&2&3&4&5&...
\end{array}